# Django REST Image upload and user profile

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Recently i am developing a mobile app (android) . For backend i am using Django REST. At first i created an user API . Which post user full name and email from google login. The main objective of my mobile app is solve user problem . Here user will upload photo from mobile app which will save under specified user already registered . Finally i want know that how can i post image in my django backend under a registered user .  If someone figured out this , please post it. Help will be highly appreciated.

Here is model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Creating krisi_user Model

class krisi_user(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Here  Serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers # imported serializers fror rest framework

from .models import krisi_user # added Model from model.py

#class for krisi_user serializer
class krisi_user_searializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # meta class for field which we want to show


    class Meta:
        model = krisi_user
        fields = ('id','full_name','email')
```

here views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets


'''importing krisi_user model and serializers 
in the views file '''

from .models import krisi_user
from .serializers import krisi_user_searializers


#class for krisi_user_view

class krisi_user_view(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = krisi_user.objects.all()
    serializer_class = krisi_user_searializers
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What you've managed to do so far? Post some example code where your problem lies.

Comment: @xbound i updated post check it please :)

Answer (score 2):

First add ImageField to your model.

1) Add image field to your model

```
from django.db import models

# Creating krisi_user Model

class krisi_user(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

2) Modify your serialiser to include image field

```
from rest_framework import serializers # imported serializers fror rest framework

from .models import krisi_user # added Model from model.py

#class for krisi_user serializer
class krisi_user_searializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # meta class for field which we want to show


    class Meta:
        model = krisi_user
        fields = ('id','full_name','email','image')
```

3) In your views.py use APIView. For uploading images you need MultiPartParser which you can add to APIView.

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser

class kriri_user_view(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = krisi_user_searializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: Thanks . I helped me lot

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad it was of help :)

If you managed to resolve your issue with the code above, do accept the answer and if you needed to make any changes to it, edit or let me know and I'll edit the answer.

This will help others who encounter this issue in future. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it won't save the file in this line:                                                             
serializer = krisi_user_searializers(data=request.data) , since you are not accessing request.FILES at all!! Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna want to use a `FileField`, as such:

```
profile_photo = models.FileField(
    upload_to='user/profile_photo', null=True, blank=True
)
```

There's good documentation of the `FileField` and how to use it at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield.

Comment: Can you tell how can  i post image in a registered user through API?